# didReceive(event: WebSocketEvent, client: WebSocket) is not called on socket?.write(string: method in Starscream

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, chat, starscream

I am using latest Starscream version of package in my chat application.Please take a look on my code snippet:-

```
import UIKit
import Starscream
import Network

class ViewController: UIViewController,WebSocketDelegate {

var socket: WebSocket!
var isConnected = false
let server = WebSocketServer()

var webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask!
var request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "wss://dev.api.deepak.com/tools/cognitive/channel/web/client")!)


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  
    request.setValue("Q6ZzGUo8q9Tta5QM0jKiZOJ03aQ3ZS", forHTTPHeaderField: "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol")
    socket = WebSocket(request: request)
    socket.delegate = self
    socket.connect()
}


func didReceive(event: WebSocketEvent, client: WebSocket) {
    switch event {
    case .connected(let headers):
        isConnected = true
        print("websocket is connected: \(headers)")

    case .disconnected(let reason, let code):
        isConnected = false
        print("websocket is disconnected: \(reason) with code: \(code)")
    case .text(let string):
        print("Received text: \(string)")
    case .binary(let data):
        print("Received data: \(data.count)")
    case .ping(_):
        break
    case .pong(_):
        break
    case .viabilityChanged(_):
        break
    case .reconnectSuggested(_):
        break
    case .cancelled:
     //   print(error)
        isConnected = false
    case .error(let error):
        isConnected = false
        handleError(error)
       // print(error)
    }
}
```

output :-

websocket is connected: ["Via": "kong/0.34-1-enterprise-edition", "Connection": "Upgrade", "Server": "nginx/1.15.6", "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=UTF-8", "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains", "X-RateLimit-Remaining-20": "499", "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "X-Auth-Token", "X-Kong-Upstream-Latency": "375", "X-RateLimit-Limit-20": "500", "Upgrade": "websocket", "X-Kong-Proxy-Latency": "386", "Date": "Thu, 30 Jul 2020 14:28:18 GMT", "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol": "Q6ZzGUo8q9Tta5QM0jKiZOJ03aQ3ZS", "Sec-WebSocket-Accept": "mkPgQAVeipWtSB+6t7soZQKWXW4=", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"]

After that I m sending message:-

```
func createChannel()
{
let message = ["request_type":"start","bot_id":"10"]

    do {
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: message)
        if let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8){
            self.socket?.write(string: dataString)
            
        }

    } catch {
        print("JSON serialization failed: ", error)
    }

}
```

it is not returning to didReceive event.

#### my api and expected response :=

URL : wss://dev.api.deepak.com/tools/cognitive/channel/web/client
Header:
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol:Q6ZzGUo8q9Tta5QM0jKiZOJ03aQ3ZS

Session start message:

Request:
{"request_type":"start","bot_id":10}

Response:
{"session_id":"1595350205841-86807685-dbc3","status":"success","request_type":"start"}

### CAN YOU PLEASE GUIDE ME WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?

Comment: Did line `self.socket?.write(string: dataString)` run when you debug ? If yes, try put a log in your server socket to investigate if server received that data and server can send any response back ?

Comment: hi @King.lbt thanks for your comment and is there any way to check from our client side means from iOS side.

Comment: If you can't debug from IOS side, just tell them to create a log service observe events / actions and input to a file. Make a button for sending an email with that logs file.